KafkaJS concurrency questions
I don't understand kafkajs completely so it would be great if someone could answer these questions:

Does partitions value have any effect on the app if we have 1 pod ap instance, 1 consumer, and 1 group? If it has an effect, then what does it do?
If we have 2 pods, then 10 partitions would result in 5 going on one instance and 5 on another and both consumers would get their set of messages(without duplicates)?
How partitionsConsumedConcurrently comes into play with question 1?

Thanks
